# Redirecting all https and http www and non www to one location

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am migrating my website to a new domain that has the same sub folder structure. I am looking to implement a redirect rule that will redirect all non www. to the new http:www. and all https:www/(non www). to the http:www.

For example the below:

https://example.com/
http://example.com/
https://www.example.com/
http://www.example.com/

should redirect to:

http://www.example2.com/

Comment: You need to add 301 redirect

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example2.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. If i run this through the "http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/" website from a https it says the output is: "http://www.example2.com:443/test/folder/struct/" so it's adding a strange ":443" in the url

Comment: I am not sure about this tester :443 is a port number I don't know why this tool add this but try it in your local setup it will work.